# How to verify that a method was called with the correct parameters with reference types?

Tags: c#, unit-testing, moq

I have the following code:

```
public class ExampleClass
{
  public void ExampleMethod(IMyInterface myInterface)
  {
    var test = new DataClass();
    test.Id = 5;
    myInterface.DoSomething(test);
  }
}

public class DataClass
{
  public int Id {get;set;}
}
```

I want to write a test that checks whether `ExampleMethod` calls `DoSomething` correctly. It is important that the `Id` property has the value 5. This is the code of the test (with Moq Version 4.14.1 as mocking framework):

```
[TestMethod]
public void Test()
{
  var mock = new Mock<IMyInterfce>();
  var example = new ExampleClass();
  example.ExampleMethod(mock.Object);
  mock.Verify(x => x.DoSomething(It.Is<DataClass>(y => y.Id == 5)));
}
```

Let's assume I have a bug in `ExampleMethod`, that I assign the value of the `Id` property too late. The buggy method could look like this:

```
public void ExampleMethod(IMyInterface myInterface)
{
  var test = new DataClass();
  myInterface.DoSomething(test);
  test.Id = 5;
}
```

The test should fail now, but unfortunately, it passes. I assume it is because `DataClass` is a reference type. When the `Verfiy` method is called, the value of the `Id` property is indeed 5, but it should be checked what the value was when `DoSomething` was called. Is there a solution to make the test fail if I have a bug like above?

Comment: You could try to make it a strict mock, and then set up the mock as, mock.Setup(x=>x.doSomething(It.is<TESTClass>(x=>x.Id==5)). In this case the mock wll execute only when the Id is 5, and any bug could be found

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Setup the mocked expectation as `Verifiable` and then verify the expectation after executing the member under test

```
//Arrange
var mock = new Mock<IMyInterface>();
mock
    .Setup(_ => _.DoSomething(It.Is<DataClass>(y => y.Id == 5)))
    .Verifiable(); //<--

var example = new ExampleClass();

//Act
example.ExampleMethod(mock.Object);
        
//Assert
mock.Verify();
```

This will cause the buggy example

```
public void ExampleMethod(IMyInterface myInterface)
{
  var test = new DataClass();
  myInterface.DoSomething(test);
  test.Id = 5;
}
```

to fail when the test is exercised.

> This mock failed verification due to the following:
>
> IMyInterface _ => _.DoSomething(It.Is(y => y.Id == 5)):
> This setup was not matched.

because at the time of invoking the member `DoSomething`, the recorded invocation did not match the expectation that was setup.